# SNMP service security tab is missing - Windows Server 2012 R2 - DC

Tags: monitoring, domain-controller, snmp, windows-server-2012-r2, system-monitoring

I have to configure the security settings for the SNMP-Service on a Windows Server. But they are missing!

Here are the facts:

- OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
- I installed the SNMP feature and I believe, that I already configured the service (but I forgot to add another IP under `Security` tab)
- I know the issue where you have to restart the SNMP-service after you installed the feature to see the `Security` tab (so I made already some restarts.)
- My colleague installed now the DC server role.
- Now I can not see the `Security` tab anymore (I don't know if it has to do something with the installation of the DC role).
- I **really need** SNMP for monitoring reasons. (So please don't advise to use WMI or other things)
- I used my domain admin when clicking on "SNMP-Service" --> "Properties"

What can I do to see the `Security` tab again? Or is there a possibility to configure the SNMP service via CMD or PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Workaround: I fixed this via Registry

I found this site for config via registry:

- Dysan, *IT Library* blog, 2010-01-28, [*How to: Set SNMP settings through registry*](http://itlibrarya.blogspot.de/2010/01/how-to-set-snmp-settings-through.html)

I set up `PermittedManagers` and `ValidCommunities`, and now it seems to work for me!

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\PermittedManagers
```

> REG_SZ
>
> Value name: 1
>
> Value data: (IP address of monitoring server)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\ValidCommunities
```

> REG_DWORD
>
> Value Data: 4
>
> Value Name: (community string)

(But if anyone has a hint why I can't see the `Security` tab under `Properties` I would be grateful anyway!)

Comment: I had the exact issue.. Missing security tab.. restarting the whole system worked for me .. https://martcj.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/snmp-service-has-no-agent-traps-or-security-tabs-to-configure-in-windows-2008/

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the SNMP Tools feature to get those tab pages, e.g. using the Powershell command `Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-SNMP`.

Remember to restart the service manager before opening the properties page again.

Comment: The OP explictly mentioned in the question that he did that.

Comment: @Sven: Where? I don't see that. Neither in the post, nor in the edit history. Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-SNMP seems correct. Just tested in lab. Blog post for background: Josh Ancel, 2013-04-02, [*Windows Server 2012 No Security Tab in SNMP*](https://joshancel.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/windows-server-2012-no-security-tab-in-snmp/)

Comment: that helped instantly.

Comment: If one just installs SNMP-Service, then they will have the missing configuration tabs under the service. You can then either manage SNMP via GPO or editing the registry. However, as Ingo notes, installing RSAT-SNMP (SNMP Tools) adds in the missing tabs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the services.msc from an elevated command line window (run as admin). Then you'll get the security tab!

Comment: Some of us IT admins are not using THE domain "administrator" account to manage server. This answer was right on.

Answer (score 1):

I read on another website that closing the service.msc waiting a few seconds and opening it again will make the agent, security and traps tabs appear. Worked for me.
https://martcj.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/snmp-service-has-no-agent-traps-or-security-tabs-to-configure-in-windows-2008/